# ckeditor upload image and error with X-Frame-Options

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, ckeditor

I'm trying to upload image by ckeditor but it give me two errors:

> Refused to display
>   'http://artafood.ca//ckeditor/uploader/upload.php?CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fa'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

ckeditor.js:553

> POST
>   http://artafood.ca//ckeditor/uploader/upload.php?CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fa
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

What's the problem??how could I solve the error and enable image upload

Comment: Have you find any solution